# Can i exclude the column used for partitioning when writing to parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

i need to create parquet files, reading from jdbc. The table is quite big and all columns are varchars. So i created a new column with a random int to make partitioning.

so my read jdbc looks something like this:

```
data_df = sparkSession.read.format('jdbc') \
    .option('url', 'jdbc:netezza://host:port/db') \
    .option('dbtable', """(SELECT * FROM schema.table) A""") \
    .option('user', 'user') \
    .option('password', 'password') \
    .option('partitionColumn','random_number') \
    .option('lowerBound','1') \
    .option('upperBound','200') \
    .option('numPartitions','200') \
.load()
```

and my write to parquet looks something like this:

`data_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("parquetfile.parquet").partitionBy('random_number')`

The generated parquet also contains the 'random_number' column, but i only made that column for partitioning, is there a way to exclude that column to the writing of the parquet files?

Thanks for any help, i'm new to spark :)

I'm expecting to exclude the random_number column, but lack the knowledge if this is possible if i need the column for partitioning

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to repartition in memory using a column but not writing it, you can just use .repartition(col("random_number")) before writing droping the column then write your data:

```
data_df = sparkSession.read.format('jdbc') \
    .option('url', 'jdbc:netezza://host:port/db') \
    .option('dbtable', """(SELECT * FROM schema.table) A""") \
    .option('user', 'user') \
    .option('password', 'password') \
    .option('partitionColumn','random_number') \
    .option('lowerBound','1') \
    .option('upperBound','200') \
    .option('numPartitions','200') \
.load()
.repartition(col("random_number")).drop("random_number")
```

then:

```
data_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("parquetfile.parquet")
```